# An error has occurred. See error log for more details

Tags: modeling, xtext, emf, eclipse-sirius

When Icreate my project EMF and my project sirius,I have this error:
My version:
Eclips version: Oxygen Release Milestone 5 (4.7.0 M5)
Sirius version: 4.1

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.sirius.ui.properties.internal.TransactionalEditingDomainContextAdapter.unregisterModelChangeListener()V
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incompatible version of eclips .